# Using Namespace and Headers

Tags: c++, c++98

I'm working on a project where I've written almost all my test code in header files. I've done this primarily because I'm doing test driven development and this results in a large amount of complementary classes for each class I add: Interface, Test, Mock etc. I think I'd go crazy if I also had to deal with cpp versions of all these files...

I don't add "using namespace std" to the start of my headers because I've learned that this is a no, no. Anyway, lets say I currently initialise my Blob object at the start of a test, as follows:

```
Blob v =
    boost::assign::list_of(std::pair<std::string, Container >("Scotland",Container(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3).convert_to_container<std::vector<int> >())))
    (std::pair<std::string, Container >("Sweden",Container()));
```

where Blob is `typedef`ed somewhere as `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Container > >`.

How can I make this prettier? The reason I'm using list_of is to make things more readable but in this case I think it makes it a lot more difficult to read. This is a lot better:

```
Blob v =
    list_of(pair<string, Container >("Scotland",Container(list_of(1)(2)(3).convert_to_container<vector<int> >())))
    (pair<string, Container >("Sweden",Container()));
```

but I can't do this in a header...

What might I do to solve this problem? I'm working with C++98.

**UPDATE:**

Just an idea. What if I renamed all my test headers to cpp files instead?

Comment: can you explain why TDD development leads to all the code in header file ?

Comment: @Pradheep Its more convenient for me at least to not have to jump around between Foo.h, Foo.cpp, TestFoo.h, TestFoo.cpp, MockFoo.h, MockFoo.cpp and IFoo.h. Instead, I just have the .h versions. I also have to create all these files and put them in the correct folders.

Comment: well putting more code on the cpp file would mean more time for compilation and harder to debug the issues as everything will be same header file.Its not the convenience of the user that is at stake here but lesser build time and better modularity

Comment: You've learned that `using namespace std;` is a no no, but putting everything in the header files is a yes yes?

Comment: Nothing keeps you from having the definitions of the Interface, Mock, and Test in the same header as the class. The same way you can put the implementation into the same `cpp` file.

Comment: @pmr Interfaces can't be in the same header as the Mock and the Test - The interfaces are used in production code, the Mock and Test only in the Test project. I also think its weird to have a Mock of an interface in the same file as a test which tests implementations of this interface. I think its better to have mocks in a mock folder in my project.

Comment: @Default I haven't learned anything with regard to putting everything in a header. I'm simply saying that if I have a Mock and Test for a given class, it is easier to have them in headers only since TDD involves jumping between different files. If I add a new function to an interface, its a real pain to have to first edit IFoo.h, then TestFoo.h, then TestFoo.cpp, then Foo.h, then Foo.cpp. And and thats just for one test case.

Comment: What if I renamed all my test headers to cpp files instead?

Comment: What is content of your "test headers"? Test cases? Why do you put them in header files? You don't need to include them anywhere!? Which test frameword do you use. Normally you put test case in footest.cpp, declarations of the test object in foo.hpp and definitions in foo.cpp.

Comment: @Pradheep Splitting the declarations and definitions of a class between a header file and a source file will not increase your build time. If anything putting all of your code in header files may **increase** build time if it is included by more than one source file. If it's only included by one source file build time will remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDD requires short edit->compilation->run cycle times. Therefore you should write as much code as possible in cpp files to reduce compilation time.
Nevertheless, you could solve your problem using a init function:

```
inline Blob InitBlob()
{
    using namespace boost;
    using namespace std;
    return assign::list_of(/*...*/);
}

Blob v = InitBlob();
```